# convertir objeto jpa a json

Tags: spring, spring-boot

que tal, estoy desarrollando una aplicacion web con spring boot y no encuentro la forma de devolver mediante una peticion ajax el resultado de una consulta jpa en formato json. Si creo una instacia de una de mis entidades y la devuelvo en el controlador con @ResponseBody funciona perfectamente pero si devuelvo un ArrayList o esa misma instancia siendo el resultado de una consulta del repository Spring tool suite se queda colgado.

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir el código relacionado para que podamos verlo? Visita el centro de ayuda y lee [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Agrega tu código para poderte ayudar

Comment: Una consulta quieres convertir la consulta jpa o el resultado de la consulta?

Answer (score 0):

Podrias usar la libreria JSONObject que viene en primefaces que es bien facil de utilizar te dejo un ejemplo:

```
 JSONObject body = new JSONObject();
    body.put("identificador", Integer.parseInt(empleadoAccion.getIdentificador()));
    body.put("accion", "bloquear");
    body.put("url", sesion.getSesion().getRequestUri());
    body.put("ip", sesion.getSesion().getIp())
```

si usas maven pues puedes agregarla al pom de esta forma

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>5.3</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
```

O puedes descargar la libreria de [aqui](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.primefaces/primefaces/5.3)